# Python // Pandas: Column Won't Rename

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The "Day" column won't rename. Could it have something to do with the "Day" column being an index and not a column? Here's my code and a sample of the unprocessed data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Load the excel file into a dataframe
df = pd.read_excel("Marginal CPA data - NOV.xlsx")

# Delete the bottom row
df = df[:-1]

# Filter the column labeled "Campaign Type (Search ACQ) - ONC" to keep only rows with value "NonBrand"
df = df[df["Campaign Type (Search ACQ) - ONC"] == "NonBrand"]

# Make a pivot table
pivot_table = pd.pivot_table(df, values=["Media Cost", "CAFE Approvals"],
                              index=["Campaign Type (Search ACQ) - ONC", "Product (ACQ Search) - ONC", "Day"],
                              columns=["CDJ"], aggfunc="sum")

df_pivot = pivot_table.fillna(value=0)

# Reset the column index to a single level
df_pivot.columns = ["_".join(col) for col in df_pivot.columns]


 # Rename columns
df_pivot = df_pivot.rename(columns={"Media Cost_CPA": "CPA Spend", "Media Cost_Non CPA (CDJ)": "CDJ Spend",
                                     "CAFE Approvals_CPA": "CPA Approvals", "CAFE Approvals_Non CPA (CDJ)": "CDJ Approvals",
                                    "Day": "Date"})
```

| Campaign Type (Search ACQ) - ONC | Product (ACQ Search) - ONC | CDJ | Day | Media Cost | CAFE Approvals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NonBrand | Consumer | CPA | 11 Jan 2023 | 29019.77415 | 94 |
| NonBrand | Consumer | Non CPA (CDJ) | 17 Jan 2023 | 24640.36448 | 86 |
| NonBrand | Consumer | Non CPA (CDJ) | 12 Jan 2023 | 23627.78256 | 78 |
| NonBrand | Student | CPA | 17 Jan 2023 | 29863.95447 | 152 |
| NonBrand | Miles | CPA | 23 Jan 2023 | 380.94 | 1 |
| NonBrand | Miles | CPA | 07 Jan 2023 | 1786.51 | 5 |
| NonBrand | Consumer | CPA | 19 Jan 2023 | 26745.81705 | 64 |
| NonBrand | Secured | CPA | 20 Jan 2023 | 1551.35 | 19 |
| NonBrand | Consumer | Non CPA (CDJ) | 02 Feb 2023 | 41185.11225 | 66 |

Comment: What does df_pivot.head().to_dict() return?

Comment: @ScottBoston it returns 
{'CPA Approvals': {('NonBrand', 'Consumer', '01 Feb 2023'): 141.0, ('NonBrand', 'Consumer', '02 Feb 2023'): 130.0, ('NonBrand', 'Consumer', '03 Feb 2023'): 105.0, ('NonBrand', 'Consumer', '04 Feb 2023'): 105.0

Answer (score 1):

[`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) might work better for a `MultiIndex`:

```
cols = {
    "Media Cost_CPA": "CPA Spend", 
    "Media Cost_Non CPA (CDJ)": "CDJ Spend",
    "CAFE Approvals_CPA": "CPA Approvals", 
    "CAFE Approvals_Non CPA (CDJ)": "CDJ Approvals"
}
indx = {
    "Day": "Date"
}
df_pivot = df_pivot.rename(columns=cols).rename_axis(index=indx)
```